# Inequivalent norms "become equivalent" on specific subset

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ be a separable Banach space and $(X',\|\cdot\|_2)$ be a dense subspace such that $\|x\|_1 \le C \|x\|_2$ holds for a constant $C>0$ and every $x \in X'.$

I know that the two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are not necessarily equivalent. However, I was wondering if there exists a set $X'' \subseteq X'$ (see below) such that $\|x\|_1 \ge C' \|x\|_2$ goes for some constant $0<C'<C$ and every $x \in X''.$

What I would like to show is that within every open ball (with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$) around some point in $X$ there lies some $x \in X'$ such that $C' \|x\|_2 \le\|x\|_1 \le C \|x\|_2.$

Are there any easy counterexamples to this that I am not aware of?

Comment: If you pick a finite dimensional space in $X'$ then both its induced norms would be equivalent. Does this answer the question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not quite sure whether in my scenario it is sufficient to consider finite dimensional spaces in $X'$. I was wondering whether every open ball $B_{\|\cdot\|_1}(y,r)$ where $y \in X$ and $r>0$ contains some $x$ such that the "equivalence inequality chain" is valid for given constants $C,C'.$

Comment: Look at $\ell_1$ in $\ell_2$. Let $x_n$ be the vector with $1$ in its first $n$ coordinates and $0$ in the others. The $\ell_2$ norm of an element in a small ball about $x_n$ is approximately $\sqrt n$, while the $\ell_1$ norm is greater than $n/2$ (for a small enough ball).

Comment: Thank you, that helps greatly!